# Firebase Database Rules - Allow write disable read on node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have this database structure:

[image: database structure]

I want the js SDK to be able to write to all the nodes. However, I want to disable `.read` on the `ip` node. So when `snapchat.val();` is called it returns everything but the `ip` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having all the details at the same level in the tree, you can create two nodes. One which you call `public` and the other which you call `private`.

Here is an example of what you could do:

[image]
[image]

Then, if you want to read the `ip` later, you could make sure that the user is authorised to be able to read the `private_info` if that is needed. Or, you could use cloud functions to do something with this data which its access is not limited by `rules`.

Comment: This looks good. However how would `public_info` be accessed. In my case `some_random_room` is not a "room" but a "message" with a randomly generated id. When detecting for `"child_added"` the call would be blocked because not all of the data is "readable".

Comment: You can access public info by doing `rootReference.child(chat/ROOM/public_info)`. I don't understand what you mean by: `When detecting for "child_added" the call would be blocked because not all of the data is "readable"`. Do you mean you want to observe wether the `ip` has had a child added to it?

Comment: After converting to all your rules:
`firebase.database().ref('chat').on("child_added", function (snapshot) { console.log(snapshot.val()); });` will not return any output because not all of the properties of the "child" node can be read

Comment: @KALEIDAGRAPH If I was you, I would use a firebase trigger within cloud functions. What would you like to do when you observe the the child being added?